# .gitignore does not exclude filetypes from ignored directory content in Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, unreal-engine4

In my Unreal Engine project directory there is a Build directory and I want to ignore all the files inside except for the png files and the keystore. I want to commit my project with Sourcetree to an empty repository which has only the README.md file.

Inside .gitignore file i have the following rules:

```
# Builds
Build/*

# Don't ignore icon files in Build
!Build/**/*.ico

# Don't ignore image files in Build
!Build/**/*.png

# Don't ignore keystore file in Build
!Build/**/*.keystore
```

Inside my project directory looks like this:

```
|   .gitignore
|   README.md
|
+---Build
|   +---AllDesktop
|   |   \---FileOpenOrder
|   |           CookerOpenOrder.log
|   |
|   +---Android
|   |   |   MyAndroidApp.keystore
|   |   |   project.properties
|   |   |
|   |   +---FileOpenOrder
|   |   |       CookerOpenOrder.log
|   |   |
|   |   +---res
|   |   |   +---drawable
|   |   |   |       downloadimageh.png
|   |   |   |       downloadimagev.png
|   |   |   |       icon.png
|   |   |   |       splashscreen_landscape.png
|   |   |   |       splashscreen_portrait.png
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   +---drawable-hdpi
|   |   |   |       icon.png
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   +---drawable-ldpi
|   |   |   |       icon.png
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   +---drawable-mdpi
|   |   |   |       icon.png
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   +---drawable-nodpi
|   |   |   |       vr_icon.png
|   |   |   |       vr_icon_background.png
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   \---drawable-xhdpi
|   |   |           icon.png
|   |   |
```

The problem is that everything inside Build is ignored but I need to keep the png files and the keystore.
I was inspired by the [UnrealEngine.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/UnrealEngine.gitignore).
What am I doing wrong ?

I want to add that it is a fresh install of sourcetree. Sourcetree also installed git, I did not have git previously installed. I don't have a global gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Sourcetree first noticed in 2015 that remains unresolved to this day:

> SourceTree for Windows does not fully honor git's gitignore pattern format.

You can check out for more details the issue jiira [SRCTREEWIN-3883](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-3883?jql=text%20~%20%22gitignore%22)

Comment: After carefully going over the issue mentioned i discovered that this is resolved just not marked as resolved and that it is unrelated to my question unfortunately. The pattern used in the issue `**/*.user` , is working in the current version of sourcetree and ignores the files with the extension .user in project but what I want to do is to ignore a directory, Build, and exclude from ignoring all the files in the Build directory that are .ico, png, .keystore, so the part that is not working for me is the exclude from ignore pattern (e.g. `!Build/**/*.ico`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try recreating the gitignore file, or possibly using a predefined gitignore for unreal engine.
https://www.gitignore.io/api/unrealengine

That has a lot more rules but could be a start.

Comment: I tried to use the predefined gitignore for unreal engine, even that doesn't work properly, for example, the line "!Build/**/*.ico" doesn't exclude the ico files. It might be a problem with the way git interprets the gitignore rules on windows or maybe there is a bug. I am using Sourcetree version 3.0.8 with git version 2.18.0.windows.1. I just have no idea why is behaving like this and I think this needs to be tested so people can see problem better.